# Kendo React Grid : Reordering columns and save the new order

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm working on Kendo react grid and a set  reorderable={true} to make the columns reordering.
Now i want to save the new order and i don't found a solution what event should i use to detect when the column move

```
      <Grid
      pageable={paginationConfig}
      reorderable={true}
      sortable
      filterable
      resizable
      style={{ height: '600px', overflow: 'auto' }}
    >......</Grid>
```

can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1):

See [onColumnReorder](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridProps/#toc-oncolumnreorder) in the Documentation. Where you store it is the next question... State, store, local storage etc...